# Word shading exactly to text height

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I'm currently working on a MS Word report.

To highlight certain sections, it would be great to shade some part of the text as seen in beneath image:

[image: This is what I want to have]

Unfortunately, I'm just able to add the shading for the full line height, as shown in the following image:

[image: This is what I got]

Is there a native way inside MS Word to accomplish the shading for just the text height?

Otherwise I'm forced to embed images inside my report as the headings (This is something I do not want for several reasons, e.g. complications in Table of Contents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to have a shading as you desire, it's always to the full line height and not the cap height. And this also makes sense, when you think about how the shading would look like for letters with a tail (such as uppercase Q or a descender (such as lowercase g).

If you want to add the shading to single lines only you could mimic the desired effect by anchoring a rectangle shape to the paragraph and position it behind the text.

Here is a quick and dirty VBA macro that adds shading using shapes to the selected lines of text. You have to fine-tune the height and vertical offset of the shapes to the font and font size you are using.

```
Sub AddShading()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim startPos As Integer
    Dim endPos As Integer

    Dim capHeight As Single
    capHeight = 8

    Dim verticalOffset As Single
    verticalOffset = 3

    ' backup original select
    Set rng = Selection.Range.Duplicate

    ' start undo transaction
    Application.UndoRecord.StartCustomRecord "Add Shading"

    Do
        ' select line of text
        Selection.Collapse
        Selection.Expand wdLine
        If Selection.Start < rng.Start Then
            Selection.Start = rng.Start
        End If
        If Selection.End > rng.End Then
            Selection.End = rng.End
        End If

        ' get range of current line to be able to retrieve position of line
        Dim rngLine As Range
        Set rngLine = Selection.Range.Duplicate

        ' get the left coordinate
        Dim left As Single
        left = rngLine.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)

        ' get the top coordinate and add a vertical adjustment depending on the font used
        Dim top As Single
        top = rngLine.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) + verticalOffset

        ' move to the end position of the line
        rngLine.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        If rngLine.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) > top Then
            rngLine.Move wdCharacter, -1
        End If

        ' calculate width of line
        Dim width As Integer
        width = rngLine.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage) - left

        ' add shape behind text
        Dim shp As Shape
        Set shp = rng.Document.Shapes _
            .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, left, top, width, capHeight, rng)

        With shp
            ' grey shading
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 192, 192) 

            ' no outline
            .Line.Visible = msoFalse 

            ' the shape should move with the text
            .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionParagraph 

            ' position the shape behind the text
            .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind 
        End With

        ' continue with next line
        Selection.Move wdLine

    Loop While Selection.End < rng.End

    ' restore original selection
    rng.Select

    Application.UndoRecord.EndCustomRecord

End Sub
```